# Group Laravel collection by the given key

Tags: arrays, api, laravel-5

in Laravel I want to change response if same user array have multiple response

I get a response with this function

**controller.php**

```
public function index(){
    $reports = Report::all();
    return $this->sendResponse($reports->toArray(), 'User Reports successfully.');
}
```

This is my **response**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 66,
            "cuid": 20,
            "name": "my1",
            "created_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
            "time": "07:19 PM",
            "status": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "cuid": 20,
            "name": "my1",
            "created_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
            "time": "07:39 PM",
            "status": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "cuid": 21,
            "name": "my2",
            "created_at": "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-05 00:00:00",
            "time": "07:01 PM",
            "status": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "cuid": 20,
            "name": "my2",
            "created_at": "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
            "time": "06:44 PM",
            "status": "D"
        }     
    ],
    "message": "User Reportsssss successfully."
}
```

This is fine my problem is i have 4 array with 2 user insted showing that way i want to show like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        my1:{
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "cuid": 20,
                    "name": "my1",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:19 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
                {
                    "id": 65,
                    "cuid": 20,
                    "name": "my1",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:39 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
        },
         my2:{
                {
                    "id": 63,
                    "cuid": 21,
                    "name": "my2",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:39 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
                {
                    "id": 64,
                    "cuid": 21,
                    "name": "my2",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-05 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:01 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
        }
    ],
    "message": "User Reportsssss successfully."
}
```

How to achive this if same user comes under single array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal way to do this would be by using collection pipelines. Your original controller method would become the following;

```
public function index(){
    $reports = Report::all();
    return $this->sendResponse($reports->groupBy('name')->toArray(), 'User Reports successfully.');
}
```

The `groupBy` method will split the collection results out into other collections, grouped by the provided column. Because the `toArray()` method cascades, you'll get a nice array back.

Answer (score -3):

You need to loop through the result and modify it as per your requirement.I have tested the below code its working fine. Try using it.

```
$reports = $reports->toArray();
$finalArray = [];

foreach($reports as $key=>$value) {
    $name = $value['name'];
    $finalArray[$name][] = $value;
}

return $this->sendResponse($finalArray, 'User Reports successfully.');
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very long winded way of doing this.

Comment: Show the better way @ollieread. If you have a better way you can downgrade my answer, if you don't have a better way you have no rights to downgrade my answer.

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Comment: It doesn't output the expected result. Can you print the output of your code?

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer @ollieread's solution is the better way to handle this with a collection in Laravel.